# VB6 - CDbl truncating problem

Tags: vb6

I'm having problems casting to a Double from a String in VB6.

```
dblValue = CDbl(strValue)
```

When strValue = 88888888888888888, dblValue = 8.88888888888889E+16, which is truncating the number during the cast.  Does anyone know of any way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information guys, I appreciate it.  I'll try implementing this with the Decimal data type.

Answer (score 3):

You could change your code to use `Decimal` instead of `Double`. That data type has the necessary precision to store the value.

Unfortunately, VB6 does not support creating variables of type `Decimal` directly, but you can store the data as a `Variant` of subtype `Decimal`, e.g.

```
Dim decValue As Variant
decValue = CDec(strValue)
```

You can manipulate this data exactly as you would any other numeric data type, you just won't have strict type-safety for the variables.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way around this, because a Double is only precise to 15 significant figures, but 88888888888888888 has 17 digits. There will be precision lost if you convert the number to Double.

You should use a Decimal type by `CDec` if you need to preserve all digits exactly.